# Is there anything that can be done to a toilet to prevent Poseidon's kiss?

Tags: bathroom, water, toilet, backsplash

I usually just use a bit extra toilet paper to prevent back splashes. But is there a permanent fix for this?

Comment: Yes - Buy a better toilet.

Comment: What kind would that be?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it _might_ be a better fit at [lifehacks.se].

Comment: Idk the answer recommends fixes to the water level in the toilet, sounds like home improvement. My solution is a life hack.

Comment: This is a real problem in the world of homeownership and has a solution/s. the solutions are not "hacks" .    It is a more legitimate question than some like, " what curtains should I buy"

Comment: Yeah I wanted to ask the pros, not people just trying to be clever.

Comment: Maybe the continental shelf toilets like in Netherlands are better for this, I'm not sure though, they still retain some water in the top part.

Comment: The permanent fix is, annoyingly, a better toilet. The American Standard and Toto low flow ones I have installed in various houses have not done this.

Comment: That sounds like an answer, if you say the one there isn't adequate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions:

If you lower the water level in the tank, the fill valve closes sooner. The result is a lower level of water in the bowl, ( less to splash.)

If your fill valve has the small tube going to the overflow there is a [Fill restrictor](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Fluidmaster-215-Water-Saving-Roller-Clamp-w-Refill-Tube?utm_source=google_ad&utm_medium=Shopping_ntm&utm_campaign=Shopping_NTM_New_users&gclid=CjwKCAjwivemBhBhEiwAJxNWN8mOcfbM6Ar9qV-dpSQ55wJ8hmYhP8HMT0DqZmsi-mHwESIThBaHlRoCXlIQAvD_BwE) that can be adjusted to lower the flow of water into the bowl, again resulting in a lower level in the bowl.

Neither of these changes the amount of water used to flush, (unless you lower the level excessively), so your flushing action will be the same. Just less water, (lower level) in the bowl.

Comment: In US toilets, water does not rise in the bowl as long as fill is active, it fills to the level of the trap and overflows out the discharge line.

Comment: @Tiger Guy,   Yes, you are correct, the idea is to add a little less water so it is farther from the level of the trap.  Most toilets can have the water level vary by more than an inch.